# Populate Contacts in picklist based on selected Account

Tags: visualforce

Populate Contacts in picklist based on selected .
If i select a picklist of Accountname--> all names will be displayed.
Then if i select a name  "conatcts" of that names must be displayed in a new picklist .

```
public with sharing class AccountController1 {
public String selectedAccId{get;set;}

       public List<SelectOption> getAccountNames() {
              List<SelectOption> accOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
              accOptions.add( new SelectOption('','--Select--'));
              for( Account acc : [select Id,name from Account ] ) {
                      accOptions.add( new SelectOption(acc.Id,acc.name)); /*SelectOption list takes two parameters one is value and other one is label .In this case account name as a label and Id is the value .*/
              }
             return accOptions;
       }
}




<apex:page controller="AccountController1">
          <apex:form >
                   <apex:pageBlock title="Account Name">
                           Account Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                               <apex:selectList value="{!selectedAccId}" size="1"> 
                                           <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountNames}" />
                               </apex:selectList>
                  </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Hi i am able to display the records of account name picklist, But if i select a picklist name its related contacts records must be displayed in a new picklist

Comment: Before you go further on trying to implement this, please consider that trying to put every Account name in a picklist is definitely going to break when there are more than 50,000 Accounts and is going to be pretty unwieldy when there are more than a few hundred Accounts. Is this code only meant to run in an org that has a small number of Accounts (and Contacts)?

Comment: It is for a small org only please help me out

Answer (score 2):

You need to nest this:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="contactsPageBlock"/>
```

inside your Account `apex:selectList` and give the containing element of a Contacts select list the id "contactsPageBlock". The Apex that provides the `apex:selectOptions` of the Contacts select list must always use the current value of `selectedAccId`.

So when the Account select list changes the Contacts part of the page is rerendered using Contacts based on the currently selected Account id.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I had used rerender in vf and apex but i am not getting 2nd picklist with related object records

Comment: ... then you will have to make use of Apex's debug logging and your browsers Developer Tools to figure out where the problem is. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking a question, but we're trying to avoid questions like "please write my code for me." 
Take a stab at the situation yourself, come back, post your code, and let's see if we can help you out.
Good luck!

Edit:

Thanks for posting your code. You should find the following code samples useful:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm
 * This shows how to use actionRegion and rerender

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Visualforce_DynamicEditPage
 * This has more explanation on how to do it.

Comment: Hi i had added a code which i am doing. I am getting account name picklist, if i select a accountname from picklist it;s child contacts must come on another picklist.